# Find volume of the region

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Find the volume of the region when B is the region
bounded by the cylinder $$x^2 + 3z^2 = 9$$ and the
planes $$y = 0$$ and $$x + y = 3$$.

$$ \int_{-3}^{3} \int_{0}^{3-x}\int_{-\sqrt{\frac{9-x^2}3}}^{\sqrt{\frac{9-x^2}3}}\mathrm{d}z\ \mathrm{d}y\ \mathrm{d}x $$

Is my integral correct?

Comment: Why do you think it could be wrong? Is there something that you are not sure?

Comment: Im not sure if i bounded the y component correctly

Comment: I think I see why. $y$ moves between $y=0$ and $x+y=3$ planes. So the first intuition is to set the limits of the integration between $0$ and $3-x$. But, if those planes intersect inside the cylinder, you have to realise that $3-x$ is negative, and technically, you would have to say from $3-x$ to $0$. Nonetheless, in this case $x$ is bounded between $-3$ and $3$, so $3-x$ is always positive and the integration limits are ok. I hope I expressed myself correctly, don't hesitate to ask if something is not clear.